# MySQL connectivity error unable to retrieve list of database

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework, mysql-workbench

I am trying to connect visual studio to MySQL and get the following error.I looked it up online but couldn't find a solution. Here is the picture of error.

[image: Error]

Comment: Have you managed to connect using the command line or with something like MySQL Workbench ?

Comment: No I haven't tried connecting using command line....can you explain what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

Well finally I downloaded the previous version of MySQL which is 5.7.22. After that I downloaded MySQL.Data and MySQL DLLs from nuGet then connected visual studio 2017 with MySQL then it established a successful connection.

Before installing previous version of MySQL you must uninstall currently installed MySQL. Hope it helps someone who is facing the same issue.

Comment: I searched for MySQL DLL in nuget package manager but I couldn't find such a package. What I found was `MySqlBackup.NET`. Is this the package that you installed?

Answer (score 0):

[caching_sha2_password](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-4-new-default-authentication-plugin-caching_sha2_password/) is the new default authentication algorithm for MySQL 8.0.4.

In order to connect to a server using that algorithm, you also need your client compiled against a compatible libmysqlclient. I guess the Visual Studio tooling hasn't been upgraded yet.

First I'd try to install the [newest Connector/.NET, starting with 8.0.11](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/8.0.html):

> [Changes in MySQL Connector/Net 8.0.11 (2018-04-19, General Availability)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-net/en/connector-net-news-8-0-11.html)
>
> Support was added for the new caching_sha2_password padding mechanism introduced in the MySQL 8.0 release series

If that doesn't work, downgrade the authentication for that user, for example to `mysql_native_password`:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '$yourPasswordHere';
```

Comment: Currently I have MYSQL connector 6.9.10 so I should remove it and intall the latest as you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using an new version (2.0.5) of MySQL for Visual Studio, and that was the problem. I had to replace it with an old version ([MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.10](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/visualstudio/)). After that, I could connect VS with my DB.

In resume:

- Visual Studio 2019
- [MySQL 8.0.36](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) configured with "Full" Option
- [MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.10](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/visualstudio/)

That's working for me. I hope, it helps you (or anybody).